# Find the big-O of a function

Tags: algorithm, big-o

Please help me on following two functions, I need to simplify them.

> O(nlogn + n^1.01)
>
> O(log (n^2))

My current idea is

> O(nlogn + n^1.01) = O(nlogn)
>
> O(log (n^2)) = O (log (n^2))

Please kindly help me on these two simplification problems and briefly give an explanation, thanks.

Comment: If this is homework, please tag it using the `homework` tag.

Comment: What's the difference between the two values on the last line?

Comment: @JRL: There is no visible difference - so O(log (N^2)) is not reducible according to his current idea.  I think that's correct.

Comment: Please don't add the homework tag for him; if it is really homework and he wants to share this information let him. LiraNuna, do you have a crystal ball? How can you know from the information he gave whether this is homework or not?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

For the second, you have O(lg(n²)) = O(2lg(n)) = O(lg(n)).

For the first, you have O(nlg(n) + n^(1.01)) = O(n(lg(n) + n^(0.01)), you've to decide whatever lg(n) or n^(0.01) grows larger.

For that purpose, you can take the derivative of n^0.01 - lg(n) and see if, at the limit for n -> infinity, it is positive or negative: 0.01/x^(0.99) - 1/x; at the limit, x is bigger than x^0.99, so the difference is positive and thus n^0.01 grows asymptotically faster than log(n), so the complexity is O(n^1.01).

Comment: +1, you could also note for clarity regarding the first example you provided, 2 is negligible since it is a *constant* and you can get rid of them in time-complexity.

Answer (score 7):

Remember:

```
log (x * y) = log x + log y
```

and `n^k` always grows faster than `log n` for any `k>0`.

Answer (score 1):

Putting things together, for the first question `O(n*log(n)+n^1.01)` the first function *grows* faster than the second summand, i.e. since `nlog(n) > n^1.01` for `n` greater than about 3, it is `O(nlog(n))`

In the second case use the formula mentioned by KennyTM, so we get

`O(log(n^2)) = O(log(n*n)) = O(log(n)+log(n)) = O(2*log(n)) = O(log(n))`

because constant terms can be ignored.